# scrapy.bat wasn't installed - scrapy is not recognized as an internal command or external

Tags: scrapy

I closely followed scrapy installation instructions yet I get the error message

> "scrapy is not recognized as an internal command or external..."

I installed **Scrapy** with **pip**. I don't have any `scrapy.bat` file and I wonder if it had something to do with it,

I ran over the **PATH instructions** several times and so it is not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I fixed it by creating a `scrapy.bat` file in the Python\Scripts folder.  I found the contents of the `scrappy.bat` file on Google:

```
@echo off

setlocal

"%~dp0..\python" "%~dp0scrapy" %*

endlocal
```

Comment: I used another program in the end but Thanks for your help!